# Self import of subpackages or not?

Tags: python, package

Suppose you have the following

```
b
b/__init__.py
b/c
b/c/__init__.py
b/c/d
b/c/d/__init__.py
```

In some python packages, if you `import b`, you only get the symbols defined in b. To access b.c, you have to explicitly `import b.c` or `from b import c`. In other words, you have to

```
import b
import b.c
import b.c.d
print b.c.d
```

In other cases I saw an automatic import of all the subpackages. This means that the following code does not produce an error

```
import b
print b.c.d
```

because `b/__init__.py` takes care of importing its subpackages.
I tend to prefer the first (explicit better than implicit), and I always used it, but are there cases where the second one is preferred to the first?

Comment: You don’t have to `import b` and then `import b.c` before `import b.c.d`.  (I tend to write `from b.c import d` to strike a balance between brevity and explicitness.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like namespaces -- so I think that `import b` should only get what's in `b` itself (presumably in `b/__init__.py`).  If there's a reason to segregate other functionality in `b.c`, `b.c.d`, or whatever, then just `import b` should not drag it all in -- if the "drag it all in" does happen, I think that suggests that the namespace separation was probably a bogus one to start with.  Of course, there are examples even in the standard library (`import os`, then you can use `os.path.join` and the like), but they're ancient, by now essentially "grandfathered" things from way before the Python packaging system was mature and stable. In new code, I'd *strongly* recommend that a package should **not** drag its subpackages along for the ride when you import it.  (Do `import this` at the Python prompt and contemplate the very last line it shows;-).

Answer (score -1):

`__all__` = [your vars, functions, classes]

Use syntax above in package b's `__init__.py` to auto load things listed in dict. :)

Comment: That affects `from b import *`, not `import b; b.c.d`.