# Python: Why isn't this submodule being loaded?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed scikit-learn with pip (`pip install -U scikit-learn`). I then went to ipython and ran `import sklearn`, but if I then try to load any modules, they aren't found. In particular, the tab completion of sklearn doesn't seem correct:

```
In [2]: sklearn.
sklearn.base          sklearn.clone         sklearn.externals     sklearn.re            sklearn.setup_module  sklearn.sys           sklearn.test          sklearn.warnings
```

Any idea what's going on here? Other modules load fine. For example, numpy works normally.

Comment: You may have to import them explicitly, i.e. `import sklearn.<submodule>`.  Many large libraries behave this way.

Comment: Good Call! Thanks Seth.

Comment: Mind if I change the title to be more helpful for other people?  I'll put my comment as an answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the submodule you want to use explicitly:

```
import sklearn.<submodule>
print sklearn.<submodule>.function()
```

or

```
from sklearn.<submodule> import function
print function()
```

In large python packages, oftentimes the submodules need to be explicitly imported.  This is so that the user can pick and choose what to import without importing the entire package (which can negatively affect startup time).

Comment: [Here's more discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824001/self-import-of-subpackages-or-not) on why the subpackages are not automatically imported.